# How to create array of a specific view and add each of them to main layout in Android

Tags: android

I am able to run following code without any issue

```
EditText[] course_name = new EditText[4];
OnCreate {
        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout_setupclass);
        course_name[0] = new EditText(this);
        course_name[0] = (EditText) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edittext, null);
        layout.addView(course_name[0]);
}
```

But app would crash when I try this

```
EditText[] course_name = new EditText[4];
OnCreate {
        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout_setupclass);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            course_name[i] = new EditText(this);
            course_name[i] = (EditText) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edittext, null);
            layout.addView(course_name[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are creating array with 4 elements capacity `new EditText[4];`, but in your iteration you have 5 in-`for`-loop calls (`i=0` to `4`). index `4` doesn't exists in array (arrays are 0-based indexed), so you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on `course_name[i]` call (when `i=4`, as max may be `3` due to size of array)

btw. calling `course_name[i] = new EditText(this);` is redundant, as in very next line you are attaching another (inflated from XML) view to this variable

Comment: Jeez that's so silly of me; spent almost half an hour over this! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: happens :) btw. post exception stactrace in comments, you can find it in `Logcat` tab in Android Studio. I bet this exception name would lead you to resolution without posting question here :) consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful, good luck!